# Django allauth - using custom form Validation errors do not show on the template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I use django Allauth for user signup and login.
I have 2 kinds of sign up forms for different kinds of users.

Setting.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.mySignupForm_1'
```

form.py

```
class mySignupForm_1(forms.Form):
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.save()



class mySignupForm_2(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, label="Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password (again)")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label='Last Name')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label='First Name')

    print('1111')   # it prints when the template is render.

    def signup(self, request, user):     
            print('22222') # this line never print. It seems the program never reach here

            # last_name and first_name are not saved in the Database. WHY?
            user.email = self.clean_data['email']
            user.last_name = self.clean_data['last_name']
            user.first_name = self.clean_data['first_name']
            user.save()
```

view.py

```
class JointLoginSignupView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    signup_form  = SignupForm
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JointLoginSignupView, self).__init__(*kwargs)        

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(JointLoginSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret['mysignupform1'] = get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup', self.signup_form)
        return ret

login = JointLoginSignupView.as_view()




class CustomSignupView2(SignupView):

    template_name = "account/merchant_signup.html"
    custom_signup_form2 = MerchantSignupForm

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupView2, self).__init__(*kwargs)       

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(CustomSignupView2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret['custom_signup_form2'] = get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup', self.custom_signup_form2)
        return ret

custom_signup_form2= CustomSignupView2.as_view()
```

url.py

```
 url(r'^signup1/', 'allauth.views.signup', name='signup1'),
 url(r'^signup2/', 'allauth.views.custom_signup_form2', name='signup2'),
```

template 1 that shows errors

```
<form class="signup_form" name="registerForm" action="{% url 'signup1' %}" method="post"> 
                        {% csrf_token %} 



                        {{mysignupform1| crispy }}

                        {% if redirect_field_value %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                        {% endif %}


                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-primary">{%trans 'Create an Account' %}</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

template 2 that doesn't show errors

```
<form class="signup_form" name="registerForm" action="{% url 'signup2' %}" method="post"> 
                    {% csrf_token %} 



                    {{custom_signup_form2| crispy }}

                    {% if redirect_field_value %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                    {% endif %}


                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-primary">{%trans 'Create an Account' %}</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

If I enter the wrong data in the custom signup_form1, it shows the error as below

[image: templates shows error]

I have 2 questions:

1. If I do the same thing in the second custom signup form, it doesn't show those errors. How to make the second form show validation errors?
2. in the form.py, the line **print('222')** in the function **mySignupForm_2** seems never to be reached. and extra fields last name and first name are not saved. Did I do anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.mySignupForm_1'`

You set `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` to customform1 in the setting file. Set it to customform2 and see what happens. The print statement should be called in this case.

However, there's no way to set multiple signup forms in django_allauth as far as I know.